# React redux-strange behavior, prevState and newState change together

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers

I started to work on some frontend project, I needed to plant foundation and I choosed to go with react and redux. I went through some tutorials and started to build my project.

Everything was working fine, but all of sudden I m stuck with problem I'm not even sure how to describe it.

Problem is connected with using redux, reducers.

In short somehow my prevState was changing with the newState. The worst part is I cant share much more information, I'm new to this react/redux, so I'm not even sure if this is even possible.
Here is the example code:

```
export default function (state: UserReducerState = initialState, action: Action): any {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    console.log(state);
    state.loginStatus.username="This change should only be on prevState";
    console.log("newState",newState);
    return newState;
  };
```

When I console.log(newState) it has the change from the old state even though the newState was copied before the state.loginStatus.username ="This change......."
I dont know what code should I show more, but this is where problem start,I think.

How is even possible that object that is copied have the refrence to the old one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Even though you are copying the state object it isn't a ***deep*** copy. You are mutating the more deeply nested properties of your previous state object since the new state is simply holding a reference to them.

```
state.loginStatus.username = "This change should only be on prevState";
```

`newState` is a new object, but `newState.loginStatus.username` is reference back to the same object the previous state holds.

## Solution

I'm not sure why you'd mutate your old state object in a reducer, but when updating the more deeply nested properties in the new state you must shallow copy ***any*** nested state that is being updated. Typically this is achieved via the spread syntax.

```
export default function (state: UserReducerState = initialState, action: Action): any {
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    loginStatus: {
      ...state.loginStatus,
      username: "This change should only be on newState".
    },
  };
  console.log(state);
  console.log("newState", newState);
  return newState;
};
```

Comment: [This](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is quite a good resource for immutable update patterns.

Comment: @HMR Ah yes, all the lessons/patterns I probably learned the hard way. Thanks, that is a great resource.